# How do I prove this transcendental equation has a solution?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, transcendental-equations

I am trying to prove that for the following equation, there is a B that solves it (c is a constant):

$1-B = e^{-cB}$

I understand this is a transcendental equation, but how do I prove there is a B that solves it?

I need a non-zero solution. c > 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** The question was changed to eliminate the solution $B=0$.

**First answer:** By inspection, $B=0$ is a solution. In the case $c=1$, it is the only solution.

**Answer to modified question:** Consider the function $f(x)=1-x-e^{-cx}$. We have $f'(x)=ce^{-cx}-1$. This is positive at $x=0$, since $c\gt 1$. Thus  by continuity $f'(x)\gt 0$ for a while after $x=0$.

It follows that $f(x)$ is increasing for a while past $x=0$, and in particular is positive for some $a\gt 0$.

When $x$ is large enough, $f(x)$ is negative, since $\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{-cx}=0$.

Thus by the Intermediate Value Theorem, there is an $x\gt 0$ such that $f(x)=0$.

**Remark:** By closer examination of the derivative, one can show that there is exactly one $x\gt 0$ such that $f(x)=0$.

Comment: I need a non-zero solution. c > 1

Comment: You are welcome.  It is an interesting sort of equation.

Answer (score 1):

Note that for $c \gt 1$, for $B$ slightly greater than zero $1-B \gt e^{-cB}$ (you can use the derivatives to show this).  At $B=1$ we have $1-B \lt e^{-cB}$ and there must be a point where they cross.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to use $x$ for $B$:

$1-x = e^{-cx}$

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1-x+%3D+e%5E%28-cx%29 solves for x as

- 1 $$x = \frac {W(-c*e^{-c} )+c} {c}$$ where W is the [product log function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_log_function).

To prove this, we need to show that $$(cx-c)e^{cx-c}+c*e^{-c}=0$$

Let's use an alternate form of the original equality(this is trivial):

- 2 $$(x-1)e^{cx}=-1$$

Assume $(cx-c)e^{cx-c}+c*e^{-c}=y$

$$(cx-c)e^{cx-c}=y-c*e^{-c}$$

Rewrite this as $$\frac {(cx-c)e^{cx}} {e^c}=y-c*e^{-c}$$

Now, from **2** we have $$(cx-c)e^{cx}=-c$$

Substituting that gives $$-\frac {c} {e^c}=y-c*e^{-c}$$

which trivially leads to $y=0$, which then leads to **1** above, using the definition  of $W$.

Comment: Could you explain how you obtain that expression for x? Because math isn't about using computer engines to solve problems.

Comment: Math is not "about" asking other people on SE to solve problems either. Why is that better than wolframalpha?

Comment: Asking questions on Math SE is about learning the concept, the way how to solve the math problem, actually you can read that the goal of Math SE isn't to "give a man a fish, but to learn him how to fish".

How can the OP solve another question using this answer? How will this answer help him in the future? And with a solution using computer engine, math is losing its beauty.

Comment: He can invert the equation the same way wolfram did it by hand.

Comment: Let's imagine that I'm the OP, and I don't know how to invert the equation, can you help me? If you know how, edit the answer and do that, then the answer would be complete.

Comment: @Stefan4024 I added some more steps and I think the holes are easily filled in.

Comment: That's better, now it's nicely explained and I hope the OP will use this method for future refence.

Comment: I think this can get even simplier:

$$(x-1)e^{cx} = -1$$
$$(cx-c)e^{cx-c} = -\frac{c}{e^c}$$
$$W(-\frac{c}{e^c}) = c(x-1)$$

$$x = \frac{W(-\frac{c}{e^c}) + c}{c}$$

Comment: Illuminating, thanks